# Clear Cell Content

Tags: excel, vba

I have the VBA code in an Excel 2013 worksheet to hide two rows (B8:B9) when B7 selection is set to 'Pass'.  That part works.

`ClearContents` closes Excel without any reason.

I want to clear those cell contents before/after the rows are hidden or unhidden.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B7").Value <> "Pass" Then
        Range("B8:B9").ClearContents
        Rows("8:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows("8:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The B8:B9 cells are Data Validation List.

Comment: You need to set the target range or you will be in an infinite loop.`if target.address="$B$7" then`

Comment: Turn events off first - `Application.EnableEvents = False`, and then set it back to `True` at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why MS Excel crashes and closes during worksheet change sub procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bug on Worksheet Change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868969/6706419). #SelfPromotion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's notes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

' make sure the cell changed is "B7"
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value2 = "Pass" Then
        Range("B8:B9").ClearContents
        Rows("8:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows("8:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```